# Expected number of probes per operation in linear probing

Tags: data-structures, hash, linear-probing

It is claimed about linear probing that if
[image: Equation]
Then the expected number of probes for operation is
[image: For random hash function]

My question is, what is epsilon ? I know that *m* is number of buckets and *n* is number of items in the table, but i have no idea what is epsilon. How should I understand this ?

Comment: Stack Overflow Questions should not depend on off-site resources to be understood. Please include the relevant details from the link directly in your question.